# Member of channel in discord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am developing discord bot via Discord.js and I need to get all the members that are in voice channel in this moment. How can I do that?
I tried

```
message.guild.channels.find(c => c.id === id here)
```

but it says that find is not a function.
Also, I tried

```
client.channels.get("name", "name of channel")
```

but it says that get is not a function.

Comment: You need to access the `cache` property before calling `.find()`, `message.guild.channels.cache.find ...`. Check out [Changes from v11 to v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html?v=12)

Answer (score 0):

DJS uses a cache, so the find function is client.channels.cache.find.